# How to override AjaxToolkit CalendarExtender date to string conversion?

Tags: asp.net, localization, calendarextender

i am using the Microsoft Ajax Toolkit [`CalendarExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) control, to add calendar drop-down functionality to a regular TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="edStartDate" runat="server" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
      TargetControlID="edStartDate" />
```

Which works fine for most client locales. It seems that the control does a server-request in order to convert a `DateTime` into a localized `String`.

For example, today (October 1st, 2012) displays fine in Arabic `15/11/33`:

[image]

And also displays fine in Lower Sorbian `1. 10. 2012`:

[image]

---

But [some locales do not display properly in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234365/net-date-to-string-gives-invalid-strings-in-vista-pseudo-cultures) **`1////10////2012`**:

[image]

In this case i need some sort of `OnFormatDate` event, that i can supply the correct localization of a date to a string. Which leads to my question:

> How to override AjaxToolkit CalendarExtender date to string conversion?

---

**Note:** Don't confuse the question with the example.

- i'm asking how to customize the conversion of a date to a string in a `CalendarExtender`
- even if i'm not dealing with a bug in .NET, it doesn't change my question
- even if i'm not dealing with a `CalendarExtender`, i'm still asking the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used the same solution i used in a native Win32 application.

The `CalendarExtender` uses the *"Short date"* format (**`d`**). The fix is to work around the bug in .NET:

```
String format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

format = FixDotNetDateTimeFormatStringsBug(format);

CalendarExtender1.Format = format; //starts as "d", the "Short date" format
```

with our helper-fixer:

```
public String FixDotNetDateTimeFormatStringBug(String format)
{
   //The bug in .NET is that it assumes "/" in a date pattern means "the date separator".
   //What .NET doesn't realize is that the locale strings returned by Windows
   // are the *Windows* format strings. 
   //The bug is exposed in locale's that use two slashes as for their date separator:
   //      dd//MM//yyyy
   //Which .NET misinterprets to give:
   //      30////11////2011
   //when really it should be taken literally to be:
   //      dd'//'MM'//'yyyy
   //which is what this fix does:

   return = format.Replace("/", "'/'");
}
```

Or, if you like more concisely:

```
CalendarExtender1.Format = FixDotNetDateTimeFormatStringsBug(
      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Answer (score 1):

In your page... at the top of it... you have something like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

Adding there something like(spanish for example)...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" UICulture="es" Culture="es-MX" %>
```

and in your scriptmanager

```
EnableScriptLocalization="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
```

will pretty much overwrite the local settings...

But i guess you only want this property to set in your CalendarExtender:

`Format="yyyy-MM-dd"` or `Format="dd/MM/yyyy"`  or however you like...

Comment: The page already is using the locale of the client browser (so no need to hard-code `es-MX` for `de-DE` users).